# Spring Neo4j CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j

I am getting the following error when I start up my spring-data-neo4j application:

```
2013-11-10 23:16:20.159:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@26f7af{/videovix,C:\Users\mario\Documents\workspace-sts-3.3.0.RELEASE\videovix\src\main\webapp}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes. Either add CGLIB to the classpath or remove the following @Configuration bean definitions: [org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:222)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:97)
  ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes. Either add CGLIB to the classpath or remove the following @Configuration bean definitions: [org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:222)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:97)
```

application-context.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
 <context:annotation-config/>
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" base-package="com.videovix.model"/>
<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.videovix.repository"/>
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg value="C:/Users/mario/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I think the problem is that Spring is looking at annotation based configuration in org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration and not injecting/using the configuration in application-context.xml. What exactly is causing this problem and how do I solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the dependency for cglib in your Maven pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

unless you use SDN advanced mapping and so include the spring-data-neo4j-aspect dependency, in which case it's already included.